# Cross refrence 2 worksheets from the same Excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to cross refrence 2 worksheets from the same Excel file using from the worksheet with the name **I** the column "S/T"  and from the worksheet with the name "R C" the colum **Ti**.
I want to save in **I.R Co** column the data values from the **"Com"** column from **"R C"** worksheet and to save in **I.R t** the data values from **Ti** column from **R C** worksheet.
So I'm thinking about applying inner join using Excel.
So I used the VLOOKUP but it doesn't work for me. Not sure why.

The excel worksheet table **I**:
[image]

And here the excel worksheet table **RC**:
[image]

Here the link for the Excel file in onedrive:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hf9ZasTKOpJuS5MHRX3UA5tbBQfihBhTllUwa_4l2yM/edit?usp=sharing

This the SQL query to select the [Co] column:

IN SQL:

```
SELECT  b.[Co]
FROM I a
INNER JOIN [R C] b
ON  a.[S/T] = b.[Ti]
```

This the SQL query to select the [Ti] column:

IN SQL:

```
SELECT b.[Ti]
FROM I a
INNER JOIN [R C] b
ON  a.[S/T] = b.[Ti]
```

Can you please help me guys? Thanks in advance for the help..

Comment: Please provide the `VLOOKUP` formula (including cell address) and the result it delivers.

Comment: Do you need DAX solution or excel solution? Can you please tag properly?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like google sheets as opposed to Excel and I'm not sure how similar those two are.

In Excel, it will work if you put something like the below in cell H2 and drag down:

```
=INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$8, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G$1:$G$8,0), MATCH("Com", 'R C'!$A$1:$N$1,0))
```

Comment: I just tried your expression but it didn't work. This excel file is just an example. Im using an excel file with the last row of the table with the name "I" is with the number 838 and with the last row of the table with the name "RC" is with the number 969. So I tried to change your expression with the following one: =INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$969, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G$1:$G$969,0), MATCH("Com", 'R C'!$A$1:$N$1,0))  Can you please help to find the solution? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try breaking it apart piece by piece (e.g. just try the MATCH(value, range, 0) and see if it returns a number) and be careful with syntax. Based on your comment, my guess is the problem might be the sheet name (is it "RC" as indicated in the comment or "R C" as indicated in the question) or the name of the column you are looking up (is it "Com" or something else)? Finally check the ranges (e.g. does the columns run from A to N or something else) and dollar signs to make sure you're freezing the right columns/rows

Comment: This might also help: https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match   The only other thing is the syntax of the sheet names, which is simply 'sheet'!range

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution to solve this problem:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$969, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G:$G,0), 6)), "", INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$969, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G:$G,0), 6))

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$969, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G:$G,0), 7)), "", INDEX('R C'!$A$1:$N$969, MATCH($E2, 'R C'!$G:$G,0), 7))
```

Thank you @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure. A few things that you might take for the future: 1) it's generally easier to do =IFERROR(value, value_if_error) rather than =IF(ISERROR(value), value_if_error, value) 2) it is generally best practice to not hard code the column/row in the INDEX function (e.g. the "6" and "7" in this answer) since if you insert/delete a column, the data that's returned will no longer be what you want and 3) It is considered best to avoid full ranges (e.g. the $G:$G here) and instead use reduced ranges like $G1:$G999 for speed and to not overwhelm Excel if you add more data/formulas